# Пользовательская структура как точка входа в программу

Tags: c#, память, структуры, clr

Может ли быть пользовательская структура быть точкой входа (main entry) в программе?

Вопрос риторический, ибо насколько мне показывает IDE, такое возможно(т.е. достаточно создать Main метод,и все пройдет на ура).

Но отсюда вытекает иной вопрос - а чем это чревато и считается ли это дурным тонном!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

точкой входа в программу в языке C# является метод [**Main**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228506(v=vs.90).aspx#Anchor_0). Этот метод обязан быть статическим. Статические элементы класса или структуры, являются самостоятельными программными единицами, не требуют наличия экземпляра для вызова и, фактически, используют имя класса или структуры в которой объявлены только для расширения собственного имени и обеспечения его уникальности. Статические члены не наследуются, не могут быть абстрактными или виртуальными,  вы можете даже писать полностью в процедурном стиле, используя только статические классы и их элементы.

Структура - это по сути класс, но с ограниченными возможностями, в котором на уровне языка запрещено использовать некоторые принципы ООП (запрещено наследование от других классов или структур, но реализация интерфейсов разрешена, остальное - следствия). Ну и да, структуры относятся к ValueType, что накладывает еще некоторые ограничения, но, в то же время, дает возможности недоступные классам. Однако по части статических элементов - структуры ни чем от классов не отличаются, разве что сама структура не может быть статической.

Поэтому, с точки зрения CLR, нет никакой разницы, к чему будет привязан метод Main, и никаких последствий от такой замены не будет. Другой вопрос. как вы будете использовать этот класс или структуру в дальнейшем, но это уже действительно другой вопрос.

Comment: "Структура - это по сути класс, но с ограниченными возможностями, в котором на уровне языка запрещено использовать основные принципы ООП (поля должны быть открытыми" с чего это вдруг поля у структуры должны быть открытыми? Может имелось ввиду не проиницилизоварнными?

Comment: @CSharpUser да, вы правы, это я с чем-то другим перепутал. Там вполне могут быть приватные поля, только тогда их нужно обязательно в конструкторе инициализировать. в случае с открытыми полями, можно обойтись без конструктора вообще

Comment: поля инициализируются в конструкторе по умолчанию, который нельзя модифицировать(в пользовательских структурах), и модификатор доступа не играет роли(будь поле помечено как Private/Protected/Public),ибо такая семантика работы конструктора по умолчанию у пользовательских структур

Comment: @CSharpUser точно, спасибо что заставили освежить знания, и за интересный вопрос =) убрал из ответа лишнее

Comment: не могу почему то адресовать вам сообщение,видимо закрыли такую возможность. Пометил ваше сообщение  как ответ.

Comment: @CSharpUser когда пишете комментарий для автора вопроса или ответа, не нужно указывать адресата через собаку, оповещение будет доставлено без этого.